# RSpec AWS Lambda handler - uninitialized constant in module

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rspec, aws-lambda

I've got a simple AWS lambda handler for Ruby 2.5.0 which I want to test. I found pretty cool [example](https://dev.to/jalerson/building-aws-lambdas-for-real-world-using-ruby-and-serverless-framework-2p49) how to do so but I'm stuck at the beginning with `uninitialized constant Bot` error.

`source/handlers/jira_handler.rb`

```
require_relative '../config/environment'

module Bot
  module JiraHandler
    extend self

    def handle(event:, context:)
      Slack::SlackMessenger.new(event).call
      { statusCode: 200 }
    end
  end
end
```

Module JiraHandler is inside of Bot module because of convention, the whole setup was made using terraform.

`spec/source/handlers/jira_handler_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Bot::JiraHandler do
  subject { Bot::JiraHandler }

  describe '#handle' do
    context 'when Jira webhook is launched' do
      let!(:payload) { File.new('./spec/support/events/event.json').read }
      let!(:context) { {} }
      let!(:event) do
        {
          'body' => payload
        }
      end

      let(:response) { subject.handler(event: event, context: context) }

      it 'responds successfully' do
        allow_any_instance_of(Slack::SlackMessenger).to receive(:call)

        expect(response).to include(statusCode: 200)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I received `NameError: uninitialized constant Bot`. How to initialize those self module object in specs?

Comment: where are you loading the `jira_handler.rb` file?

Comment: I'm loading all code in `spec_helper.rb` by `-I source`

Comment: So, `-I` doesnt actually load files .... Why don't you `require` the jira_handler file from spec_helper.rb?

Comment: Ok sorry, I've got this `-I` in `.rspec` file. However even if I require `jira_handler` in spec_helper.rb by `require "../source/handlers/jira_handler"` I've got an error - `LoadError:cannot load such file -- ../source/handlers/jira_handler` - the same error occurs when I'm trying to require path directly from the spec file by `require '../../../source/handlers/jira_handler'`

Comment: Use require_relative

Comment: Damn it works, thanks! However it is really strange that all other files are loaded by `-I` except this one.

Comment: What the -I flag does it add the folder to the load path, this let's you use require instead of require_relative. Not sure exactly what's not working in your case